# Haskell - reading from file into specific array

Tags: file, haskell

I'm having a Garph defined like this:

```
type Edge = (Int, Int)
type Graph = [Edge]
```

and i also have list with nodes:

```
nodes :: [Int]
```

where I have all the nodes of my graph.
And I want to read those nodes and graph from file but I can only use Prelude, System.IO and System.Enviorment .
I've tried something but I haven't been able to work on that lists later.

My file looks like

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1)]
```

but I can change it if it'll be easier to read them. I would be grateful if someone can help me.

@edit
reading from file looks like this

```
getFirstLine input = head (lines input)

start :: IO()
start = do
    contents <- readFile "test.txt"
    let nodes =  getFirstLine contents
```

but it doesn't work
I would like to assign those nodes to my

```
nodes :: [Int]
nodes = []
```

so I can use functions available for lists

@edit2

```
start :: IO()
start = do
    contents <- readFile "test.txt"
    let (line1, line2) = firstTwoLines $ lines contents
        nodes = readNodes line1
        edges = readEdges line2
    print nodes
    print edges
    print nodes
    print graph
    print hamiltonianCycles nodes
    print eulerianCycles
```

Comment: I've tried to use 
contents <- readFile "test.txt" and then assign the first line to nodes so I can use it without passing it to every single function I wanted to do the similar thing with the second line.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: *"it doesn't work"*. What doesn't work? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I'm getting different errors recently 'Last generator in do {...} must be an expression'

Comment: sometimes also 'Instance of Num [Char] required for definition of main'

Comment: You could start your troubleshooting efforts my considering the type of `nodes`. Hint: it's *not* `[Int]`...

Comment: I know it's not Int, but that's the problem I wanna read it or somehow convert it to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the file consists of two lines, each of which needs to be read separately.

First, lets get the first two lines:

```
firstTwoLines :: [String] -> (String, String)
firstTwoLines (x1:x2:_) = (x1,x2)
```

Now you can read the two lines as separate variables

The conversion from String to [Integer] (or to any other type) is done by the "read" function. This throws an exception if the string doesn't match the expected format. Each type has its own "read" function, so you need to be definite about the type you are expecting.

The type of "read" is:

```
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

In other words the type you are reading has to be an instance of the "Read" class. All of the basic types are instances of "Read", and tuples and lists of instances are also instances. In other words "read" can handle both of your lines.

So you can have

```
readNodes :: String -> [Int]
readNodes = read

readEdges :: String -> Graph
readEdges = read
```

By being specific about the return type we make each of these call the right implementation of "read". You can do this implicitly, but if you make a mistake you just get a "no parse" exception at run time and no clue as to why.

Now you can write

```
main = do
   contents <- readFile "test.txt"
   let (line1, line2) = firstTwoLines $ lines contents
       nodes = readNodes line1
       edges = readEdges line2
   print nodes
   print edges
```

Obviously you can replace the last two lines by whatever graph processing you want to do, but that will be enough to confirm that you are reading the file properly.

Comment: It works when I put it into another file but if I use it with another code placed after that then I get "Last generator in do {...} must be an expression"

Comment: @Meii "Last generator in do must be an expression" is about the "do" clause. You can't have a "let" clause as the last thing in a "do", because the "do" itself has to have a value. You probably want to "return (nodes, edges)", or else compute some more things in the "let" and then print the results. BTW, note that "print nodes" returns a "IO ()" value, which is still a return value.

Comment: It's not about having let at the end, I add my start function to my post, I don't have let at the end but I still have that error. It all worked before I add reading graph from file but I have to read it.

Comment: If I remove some whitespaces I'm getting another error ' Type error in application
*** Expression     : print hamiltonianCycles nodes
*** Term           : print
*** Type           : d -> IO ()
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c; 
Can I somehow make edges and nodes global so I dont have to pass it as argument? cause it worked before

Comment: You probably need to say "print $ hamiltonianCycles nodes". But it would help if you posted the code you are having difficulty with. Also, note that whitespace is significant in Haskell.

Comment: It was probably notepad settings it seems to work now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure you turn tabs off. Tabs are legal lexically, but cause no end of confusion in practice.